# How do I prove this limit (multivariable limit)?

Tags: limits

I evaluated this on the computer to be 0.5, but I need to prove it.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

I really want to just combine $N$ and $n$, so the limit is obviously 0.5, but am I allowed to do that? $N$ and $n$ are both going to infinity, but since infinity is more a concept than a value, is that mathematically sound?

If not, is there a way to solve this without combining the two terms?

My other thought process was to apply L'hopital's rule (sort of) and take the derivative of both $N$ and $n$ so I'd get $\frac{1+1}{1+1+2} = \frac{1}{2}$, but I don't think that really works either.

Comment: I believe the limit is zero. $$\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}=\frac{\frac{n}{N}+\frac{1}{N}}{\frac{n}{N}+1+\frac{2}{N}}$$ so taking the limit with respect to $N$ first, using algebra of limits, gives $\frac{0}{1}=0$

Comment: Are for both variables $n\to \infty$, $N\to \infty$ or $n\to +\infty$, $N\to +\infty$?

Comment: Probably what you actually want is to make $(n,N)$ go to $\infty$ along the diagonal (or a neighborhood of it) or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is written we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(0\right)=0$$

Comment: Would there be a difference if $N$ were the outside limit and $n$ were the inside limit?

Comment: @SchrodingersDog In this case we have $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}\right)\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1\right)=1$$

Comment: I probably didn't give enough context then because it's part of a larger limit. Basically I'm evaluating a limit of a product operator (the evaluation of which gives this post's limit), which comes from a ratio test of a summation. The summation itself has the $N$ limit, and the $n$ limit comes from applying the ratio test. I don't know if that changes anything, but I know the above limit in the context that I'm evaluating it to is 0.5 so this is quite confusing, but thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @SchrodingersDog You could post the original problem here in your question or making a new question on that. Of course the value for the limit depends upon $n$ and $N$ tend to infinity. Abd indeed for $n=N=t \to \infty$ the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{N\to\infty}(\prod_{v=1}^{N+2}\frac{n+v}{n+v+1}))$

Upon evaluation, I arrived at this post's limit.

Comment: @SchrodingersDog This product telescopes to $\frac{n+1}{n+N+3}$ and taking th elimit we obtain zero. What about $n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128747/discussion-between-schrodingersdog-and-user).

Answer (score 3):

Let, for every $n \geq 0$,
$$u_n = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}\right)$$

One clearly has $u_n = 0$ for every $n$, so
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n+N+2}\right)\right) = \lim_{n\to+\infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to+\infty} 0 = 0$$